# Automatically turn off/on bluetooth on shutdown/startup

Tags: windows-10, macos, bluetooth, boot-camp

I'm dual booting Win10 / OSX via bootcamp on a Macbook Pro touchbar.

When I switch to Windows, my bluetooth mouse will not connect (or with great difficulty) unless I have disabled bluetooth before shutting down OSX. I believe there is a an issue where OSX is somehow holding the bluetooth pairing of the mouse, making it problematic in Windows. If I first disable bluetooth in OSX, then Win10 connects to the mouse 100% no problems.

For this reason, I want to have a way to automatically disable bluetooth when I restart or shutdown OSX, and vice versa when OSX starts up. Then I won't be forgetting all the time to do it manually.

Comment: `brew install sleepwatcher`. I think it also can monitor shutdown event.

Comment: @DavidDai - nothing on the brew site or the dev's site says anything about shutdown/restart.  Are you sure this works for shutdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using two different tools:

- [Blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/) (free) which is a command line utility to control the Bluetooth radio (no native way to do do this in macOS).  You can get more info from [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47503/how-to-control-bluetooth-wireless-radio-from-the-command-line).  However, the command (once Blueutil is installed) would be:

  ```
  $ blueutil off      ← Turns off Bluetooth radio
  ```
- [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/index.html) allows you to run scripts/commands at certain events like shutdown, restart, your location, USB device detection and more.    I've been testing this for the last few days and so far, it seems to work really well. It's not free, but at £4, it's fairly inexpensive to solve the problem.

I'd normally use `launchd`, however, there's no way to use it to launch a script at shutdown and the only way is to [write your own shutdown hook](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/services/services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH219-CHDCEBBJ).

Answer (score 0):

Allan's answer no longer works on recent versions of macOS because [blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/) is outdated and can't be compiled against modern SDKs. [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/index.html) is still available though, and instead of blueutil Applescript can be used. I modified [some scripts posted on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applescript/comments/k4gqh3/setting_bluetooth_with_applescript_in_big_sur/) to work:

**bluetooth_on.scpt**

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "ControlCenter"
        set BluetoothButton to menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
        click BluetoothButton
        delay 1
        set OnSwitch to checkbox "Bluetooth" of group 1 of window "Control Center"
        if value of OnSwitch is 0 then
            click OnSwitch
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

**bluetooth_off.scpt**

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "ControlCenter"
        set BluetoothButton to menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
        click BluetoothButton
        delay 1
        set OnSwitch to checkbox "Bluetooth" of group 1 of window "Control Center"
        if value of OnSwitch is 1 then
            click OnSwitch
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Usage:
`osascript bluetooth_off.scpt` or `osascript bluetooth_on.scpt` and then use these from EventScripts.

Answer (score 0):

i need a windows version :( I using tp-link ub500 bluetooth adaptor because my onboard bluetooth stammer sounds. But ub500 won't turn off after shut down my pc. And my headset waiting for connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159461)